# GraphViz's executables not found

Tags: python, graphviz

I do have graphviz in the following location

**C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\graphviz**

[image]

and in the envirnment

[image]

but I still get an error code

> GraphViz's executables not found

Answer (score 9):

Actually I solved it by adding the following

```
import os     
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\graphviz'
```

Comment: @user9359930, there couldn't be a more perfect answer than this!! Thanks a ton!!